# In $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, is $(a+b\cdot r)$ a random value for fixed $a,b$ and random $r$?

Tags: randomness, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime number.
Consider two fixed values $a,b\in\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, where $b\neq0$, and a uniformly random value $r\leftarrow \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Is $v=a+b\cdot r$ a uniformly random value in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. For fixed $a\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $b\in(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\ast$ — note that $b$ must be invertible modulo $n$, which need not necessarily be a prime (but if it is, invertibility is equivalent to $b\neq0$), the map
$$ f\colon\;\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z,\; r \mapsto a+br $$
is a bijection, hence it preserves uniform distribution. That is: If $R\colon\;\Omega\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a uniformly distributed random variable, then $f(R)\colon\Omega\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is as well.

The direct argument is: If $\forall y\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z.\;\Pr[R=y]=1/n$, then for any $x\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$,
$$ \Pr[f(R)=x] = \Pr[a+bR=x] = \Pr[R=b^{-1}(x-a)] = 1/n \text, $$
therefore $f(R)$ is uniformly distributed on $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/28995/how-to-prove-any-change-to-v-a-cdot-yb-maks-y-a%E2%88%921-cdot-v%E2%88%92b-uni-rand/29000?noredirect=1#comment66728_29000

Comment: Is $v=a\cdot y+b$ a uniformly random value where $a,b$ are uniformly random values and $y$ is a fixed value? I'm considering a  field $\mathbb{F}^*_p$. Thank you

Comment: @user13676 Where are you stuck in trying to answer this question by yourself? Try coming up with an argument similar to the proof above.

Comment: I seems it is not uniformly random in field [1,p). Because it depends on the distribution of both $a$ and $b$. But why $v$ is uniformly random in [0,p) field? I'm getting confused. Shall I ask a separate question?